# Confusion about WPF binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I am trying to bind a 2D array of buttons arranged in stackpanels to a 2D ObservableCollection...

Yet, I'm afraid I don't understand something very elementary about binding.

My XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemsAsButtons">
        <Button Content="{Binding}" Height="100" Width="100"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PanelOfPanels">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DayNumbers}" ItemTemplate="   {DynamicResource ItemsAsButtons}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

...
        <ItemsControl x:Name="DaysPanel" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Row="2"
                      ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource PanelOfPanels}"/>
```

My C# code:
The backend:

```
/// <summary>
/// Window BE for Calendar.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Calendar : Window
{

    private CalendarViewModel _vm;
    public Calendar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = new CalendarViewModel();
        this.DataContext = _vm; 
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
class CalendarViewModel
{
    CalendarMonth _displayedMonth;
    EventCalendar _calendar;

    public CalendarViewModel()
    {
        _displayedMonth = new CalendarMonth();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<int>> DayNumbers
    {
        get
        {
            return _displayedMonth.DayNumbers;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to populate the buttons with values from CalendarViewModel.DayNumbers - yet the buttons do not appear. I'm clearly doing something wrong with my binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Like Igor said, you need specify `ItemsSource={Binding DayNumbers}` in outer-most `ItemsControl`, otherwise, it binds to the `DataContext`, which is `CalendarViewModel` and it is not `IEnumerable`.
2. Once you do that, it will apply `<DataTemplate x:Key="PanelOfPanels">` for each item inside `DayNumbers`. Note that the `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate` in each element in `DayNumbers`, which is of type `ObservableCollection<int>`. Here you cannot specify `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DayNumbers}"` as `DayNumbers` is not a valid property in `ObservableCollection<int>`. Instead, since `ObservableCollection<int>` is already a `IEnumerable`, it should be fine not specifying `ItemsSource` since it will by default bind to `DataContext`.
3. Finally, it goes to your inner-most `<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemsAsButtons">`, and you can put button there as what you did.

Hope it clarifies a little bit. Sorry I don't have the environment to test it out and give you the solution.

Debugging WPF bindings is not straightforward. One tip is you can use dummy converter and set breakpoint in the `Convert` method to see what it binds.

```
public class DebugConverter1 : IValueConverter
  {
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return value;
    }

    #endregion
  }

{Binding Converter={StaticResource debugConverter1}}
```

Comment: Now I understand - I needed to specify a plain binding in the upper tier list, I can see what Igor was saying now.

Answer (score 3):

Change all your `DynamicResource` to `StaticResource`. This shouldn't stop it working, but might be inefficient at runtime. Have a look [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx) for WPF resources overview.

Also your `ItemsControl` is not bound to `DayNumbers`. Add a binding like so:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="DaysPanel" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.Row="2"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PanelOfPanels}"
                  ItemsSource={Binding DayNumbers}/>
```

When you set the `DataContext` on Calendar window you set which object will be the default binding source for the whole window. You didn't specify which property of your ViewModel is bound to the `ItemsControl`. This is what the code above does.

**EDIT** Because you are overriding the item template for the `ItemsControl` and provide a collection container there, you need to provide the `ItemsSource` for it as well. The syntax `{Binding}` simply means **bind to each member or enumeration**, in this case `ObservableCollection<int>`.

Just to reiterate, the template is exactly that - a template for displaying data. It should be reusable, you should be able to bind it to whatever model you want. A rule of thumb - the data binding to actual data should happen on the control, not the template.

Comment: Doesn't the code in the template provide the binding?

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DayNumbers}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemsAsButtons}">

I've tried adding the line of code you reccomended to the actual invocation of the ItemsControl, but that didn't help.

Comment: I missed that bit. Never tried it that way, seems very awkward. The template is supposed to define the look and feel of the control, not bind to data.

Comment: The line in the template turns out to be mandatory, but had to be changed to ItemsSource="{Binding}".
You are saying that the template should not provide binding - is there a way around this (Other then manually binding in the C# code)